# Stellar standalone and network fees

Tags: stellar-core, fees

I am building a non-financial app using Stellar. Basically the app is going to transfer assets between accounts. So I want to run a few standalone nodes under same (private) network.

As far as I understand there is no way of disabling transaction fees. *Who I am I paying this fees to?* I understand the concept of inflation and fees in Stellar, but I don't understand how the standalone node and private networks work. *Do private nodes interact with public network thus needing to pay the network fee?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the fee can be set by the core administrator. See [/upgrades?mode=set](https://www.stellar.org/developers/stellar-core/software/commands.html#http-commands). What happens if you set it to zero?